# opengeo suite and pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, boundless-suite

I need help with how to add access to my computer.  When I edit the pg_hba.conf i still get the access denied error.  I just want to give a specific ip access to all db and all users from that ip... no encryption.

I am using opengeo suite 3.0.2 and pgsql 9.1.

Answer (score 1):

A few things would be helpful:

- the error message you are getting back when trying to connect
- the entry you set up in pg_hba.conf

But basically you should be able to enable the remote connection by:

1. Add the entry for pg_hba.conf for the IP and user, with "trust" as the authentication method.
2. Ensure that postgresql is listening on all network interfaces, and not just localhost. You can do this in postgresql.conf, just serach for the "listen_addresses" parameter.